# Forgot Password Implementation using Ionic Authentication

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic-cordova app using angularjs,
for that i used [Ionic Service](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/user-overview) to store and manage the users, everything is going well (sign up, login, logout), but the problem i am not able to implement the "forgot my password" functionality. 
The only function relative is [resetPassword](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/user-usage#resetting-a-users-password) but it requires the user to be logged in or (recently logged in).

Any idea of how to implement this functionality?

**Edit**:
I found a solution (listed below) but will keep the question open in case of any better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some logic to do it,
I will be storing the users IDs (generated by ionic) in my database, logic series will be like this:

1- A user clicks on forget password in the app

2- The user enters his email

3- The app will send a request to (My server), by this request my server 
should get the ID of that user

4- Extra verification step can be done here (by sending a confirmation email first)

5- When step 4 complete, my server should request a password reset using the [ionic api](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/api-users)  (post https://api.ionic.io/users/{uuid}/password-reset)

6- That sould send a temp password to the user

For sure the server should have a token to request the pass reset from ionic, which can be generated form ionic dashboard